# How to stub method in active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got a line of code in my controller that looks like this:

```
user.calendar.upcoming_events
```

where "upcoming_events" is an api call.  I'm creating tests for a the user controller and and I want to avoid actually doing the API call in my tests.  How do I stub out "upcoming_events"?

I was hoping this would work, but so far it hasn't.

```
let(:calendar) { double(:calendar, upcoming_events: []) }
before
  user.stub(:calendar).and_return(calendar)
  sign_in user  
end

get :index 

it { response.should be_success }
```

This throws

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `upcoming_events' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea what I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I would use rspec's stub_chain method.

```
user.stub_chain(:calendar, :upcoming_events).and_return(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
some_variable = stub :method_name => :return_value
```

This stubs out whatever your method is.

Check out this video too [Codeship](http://blog.codeship.io/2013/06/11/testing-tuesday-9-stubbing-and-mocking-with-rspec.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your particular combination of rspec calls per se, as the following will succeed:

```
describe 'rspec test' do
  user = Object.new
  let(:calendar) { double(:calendar, upcoming_events: []) }
  before { user.stub(:calendar).and_return(calendar) }
  it { expect(user.calendar.upcoming_events).to eq([]) }
end
```

Can you share the full error output, including stack trace?